# Error "Path/File Not Found" using the CopyFile method

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am trying to save a sheet as a PDF file to the desktop then copy the file to another location, using the `CopyFile` method.

I get errors

> "File Not Found"

or

> "Path Not Found"

When using the `CopyFile` method it creates a file on the desktop, then throws errors copying the file.

Previous to this I tried creating the pdf twice, one after the other, and it creates on the desktop and creates another in the relevant monthly folder.

I tried different syntaxes regarding the two variables.

```vb
Sub Save_Invoice_To_PDF()

Dim Fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim Invoice As Worksheet
Dim Fname As String
Dim Path1 As String
Dim Path2 As String
Dim PndSign As String
Dim Mth As String
Dim Mth1 As String

Set Invoice = Sheet1

PndSign = Chr(163)

Mth = Invoice.Range("A16").Value
Mth1 = MonthName(Month(Mth))

Path1 = "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\"
Path2 = "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Business\Sent Invoices\" & Mth1 & "\"
Fname = Range("C16").Value & " " & Range("A8").Value & " " & _
  PndSign & "" & Range("E46").Value _
  & " " & Format(Range("A16"), "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".pdf"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
  Filename:=Path1 & " " & Fname, _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  OpenAfterPublish:=False
  
Set Fso = New FileSystemObject

Fso.CopyFile Source:="C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\" & Fname, _
  Destination:="C:\Users\Peter\Business\Invoices\Sent Invoices\ _
  " & Mth1 & "\"

Set Fso = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I would like to save one pdf to the desktop and copy that pdf to a monthly folder that is designated in the `Mth1` variable which is obtained in part from the files `Fname` variable, i.e. `Format(Range("A16"), "dd-mm-yyyy")`.

Comment: The .CopyFile code will not compile because the _ strings are broken? please post the real code.  Note that the Mth1 directory must exists, it will not be created.  There is a built in FileCopy() function so you can remove the unnecessary FSO code.

Comment: Does `"C:\Users\Peter\Business\Invoices\Sent Invoices\ _
" & Mth1 & "\"` exist at the time you're trying to copy a file to it? If not, I'm fairly certain the `.CopyFile` will fail. You will have to _create_ the directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, `"C:\Users\Peter\Business\Invoices\Sent Invoices\ _
" & Mth1 & "\"` is probably not valid at all with  " _ " in the actual path. If you're trying to do a line continuation with the `_`, you need it to be _outside_ the quoted string. In your `FSO.CopyFile` line, you can use `Destination:=Path2` to save yourself from typos especially since you declared `Path2` and haven't otherwise used it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and from what I saw, this question is asked by many. I think you create the problem when before the FileCopy command there is a command to create the folder that will copy the file. So a compiler that is faster than the hard drive just can't find the folder, because that's what you're creating right now.
If you put a delay of 1 second **before the command FileCopy** ,
like this..

**Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))**

the problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running in such a way, that it is trying to copy the file before it is being created.
I use sleep and while loop if file exist in particular directory then move the next command or wait or sleep.